# How to access trigger event properties in a Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job config that uses the "Build whenever the specified event is seen" trigger (supported by the Cloudbee's Notification API plugin) and specifies a Jmespath Query (e.g. ref=='refs/heads/master') and runs a pipeline script.  I want to access other properties in the trigger event (e.g. repository.full_name) from within the pipeline script.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.  The data I was looking for is in the com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.pipeline.events.EventTriggerCause instance of the build causes.  For example, the following code finds all the commits:

```
  def newCommits = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses().findAll {
    it instanceof com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.pipeline.events.EventTriggerCause
  }.collect{
    it.getEvent().commits
  }
```